# Calculating percentage of days covered in a range with a groupby Pandas function

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a simple `Pandas` `dataframe` where each row represents a person and a date range. For each person, I'd like to know what percentage of days in a hard-coded range (defined by variables `period_start` and `period_end`) are covered across the various entries in the `dataframe`.

I assume there is an easy way to do this with `Pandas`, but I haven't been able to find one. I have a solution with multiple `dataframes` and several nested loops, but this is inefficient at scale. How can I do this more effectively utilizing `Pandas`? I think a `groupby` makes sense, but not sure how to do that when the ranges are across two columns and may overlap.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['2016-01-01', '2016-01-31', 'A'],
                        ['2016-02-02', '2016-02-10', 'A'],
                        ['2016-03-01', '2016-04-01', 'A'],
                        ['2016-01-01', '2016-03-01', 'B']],
                  columns=['startdate', 'enddate', 'person'])

# start and end date
period_start = datetime(year=2016, month=01, day=01)
period_end = datetime(year=2016, month=12, day=31)

# dates_dfculate totals days
total_days =  (period_end-period_start).days  + 1

# convert columns to dates
df['startdate']= pd.to_datetime(df['startdate'],  format='%Y-%m-%d')
df['enddate']= pd.to_datetime(df['enddate'],  format='%Y-%m-%d')

# create a TimeIndex dataframe with columns for each person
rng = pd.date_range(period_start, periods=total_days, freq='D')
people = list(set(df['person'].tolist()))
dates_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[people], index=rng).fillna(False)

# loop over each date (index)
for index, row in dates_df.iterrows():

   # loop over each column (person) 
   for person in people:
       tmp = df[df['person'] == person]

       # loop over each each entry for the person
       for index1, row1 in tmp.iterrows():

           # check if the date is date index in dates_df is within range
           value = row1['startdate'] <= index <= row1['enddate']

           # if it's not already set to true, set it to true
           if dates_df.ix[index, person] == False and value == True:
               dates_df.ix[index, person] = True

# for each person, show the percentage of days in range that are covered
for person in people:
    print  person, sum(dates_df[person].tolist())/float(total_days)
```

Desired Output:

```
A 0.196721311475
B 0.166666666667
```

Comment: What do you expect your desired output to ***look*** like?

Comment: It's just loops over each person and prints out the percentage. Added the output to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be it, I'm guessing since you're adding 1 to the total days you want to be inclusive on the ranges, but edit it as needed :)

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['2016-01-01', '2016-01-31', 'A'],
                        ['2016-02-02', '2016-02-10', 'A'],
                        ['2016-03-01', '2016-04-01', 'A'],
                        ['2016-01-01', '2016-03-01', 'B']],
                  columns=['startdate', 'enddate', 'person'])

# start and end date
period_start = datetime(year=2016, month=1, day=1)
period_end = datetime(year=2016, month=12, day=31)

# convert columns to dates
df['startdate']= pd.to_datetime(df['startdate'],  format='%Y-%m-%d')
df['enddate']= pd.to_datetime(df['enddate'],  format='%Y-%m-%d')
df['days'] = df.apply(lambda x: max((min(x.enddate, period_end) - max(x.startdate, period_start)).days + 1, 0), axis=1)

#percentage of days in range by person
people_pct = df.groupby('person').apply(lambda x: x.days.sum() / ((period_end - period_start).days + 1))
print(people_pct.head())

-----------------
    person
    A    0.196721
    B    0.166667
```

You're on the right track - pandas `groupby` is great for segmenting data, but the real power comes from the `.apply()` function, which can do either a common math transformation (mean, std, etc) or, as in this case, a custom function.

The `lambda` within the apply is saying "for each row/column (depending on the `axis`) within the group, do this custom function and return a `Series`".

While this covers your question, it's still lacking in detecting unique days, so we're assuming the rows are split with no overlap as your example stated.

Comment: This is a really great and clean solution.

Comment: thank you!  I recommend you look into http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html.  It's a great paradigm of thinking while cleaning data

Comment: I realize that the code will double count days if there are overlaps which can yield a percentage of over 100%. For example, if the data was `[['2017-01-01', '2017-01-02', 'A'], ['2017-01-01', '2017-01-03, 'A']]` Any ideas for fixing this?

Comment: yes! but you're holding my correct answer to your original question ransom, rude :).  you'll want to groupby the user, write a function that creates a list of datetime objects for every day between startdate and enddate for each row of the user, then return the `set` of that.

Comment: ha ok, sounds a bit complex. I unchecked the best answer because your answer happens to work with my dataset, but I don't think the solution satisfies the actual answer since you can't have more than 100%. That being said I reselected best answer :)